# Use signal handle to shut down flask-socketio server

Tags: server, python-3.7, shutdown, flask-socketio

I am using macOS Mojave and Python 3.7. In my work, I want to shut down flask-socketio server completely from the signal handler, which is defined as SignalHandler in my code. I noticed that, without the signal handler, the server can be shut down completely with Ctrl-C. However, the signal handler is necessary for my work. I searched online and couldn't find the solution to shut the server down in my case. For your information, I found solutions to shut the server down by "[call flask-socketio stop from HTTP or SocketIO handler function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51961426/12058289)", or "[shut down a gevent (pywsgi) server gracefully](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18277048/12058289)".

The example code is given as below:

```
import os
import threading
import signal
import requests

from flask import Flask, send_from_directory
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, Namespace
import eventlet


class WebsiteCreator(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def run(self):
        app = Flask(__name__, template_folder="templates",
                    static_folder="templates/static")

        app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'Secret!'
        socketio = SocketIO(app, engineio_logger=True, logger=True)

        # Create a URL route in our application for "/"
        @app.route('/')
        def test_page():
            """
            This function loads the homepage
            """
            return send_from_directory(
                os.path.join(app.root_path, 'templates'),
                "index1.html"
            )

        @app.route('/stop', methods=['POST'])
        def shutdown_server():
            """
            This function stops the flask-socketio server
            """
            print("Received request to shut down the server.")
            socketio.stop() #something wrong here, but don't know how to solve
            return "The server has been shut down."

        class MyCustomNamespace(Namespace):
            def on_connect(self):
                print("Client just connected")

            def on_disconnect(self):
                print("Client just left")

            def on_messages(self, data):
                print(f"\nReceived data from client: \n {data}\n")
                return data

        socketio.on_namespace(MyCustomNamespace('/channel_A'))

        try:
            eventlet.wsgi.server(
                eventlet.wrap_ssl(eventlet.listen(("localhost", 8080)),
                                  certfile='server.crt',
                                  keyfile='server.key',
                                  server_side=True), app)
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Website is not established due to:\n{e}")


# Terminate code from shell
class SignalHandler(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def __call__(self, signum, frame):
        print("Shutting down the website.")

        # Begin 'something' here to shut down the server...
        shutdown_server = requests.post("https://localhost:8080/stop", data=None)
        print(f"Shut down the server feedback: {shutdown_server}")
        # 'Something' ends here

        print("The website has been shut down.")


if __name__ == '__main__':

    WebsiteCreator().start()

    # If the following part is not included, the server can be shut down using Ctrl-C
    handler = SignalHandler()
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, handler)
```

In the code, I am running the flask-socketio server in a thread. I want to shut the server down by doing some actions in the SignalHandler.

Yet, when I exited the system with Ctrl-C, some exceptions raised:

```
^C
Shutting down the website.
(23066) accepted ('127.0.0.1', 49720)
Received request to shut down the server.
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Nov/2019 13:08:18] "POST /stop HTTP/1.1" 200 0 0.000365
wsgi exiting
Exception ignored in: <module 'threading' from '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/threading.py'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 1308, in _shutdown
    lock.acquire()
  File "web_app.py", line 74, in __call__
    shutdown_server = requests.post("https://localhost:8080/stop", data=None)        
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 116, in post
    return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 60, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 533, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 646, in send
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/eventlet/hubs/kqueue.py", line 105, in wait
    readers.get(fileno, hub.noop).cb(fileno)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/eventlet/greenthread.py", line 221, in main
    result = function(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/eventlet/wsgi.py", line 818, in process_request
    proto.__init__(conn_state, self)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/eventlet/wsgi.py", line 357, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/eventlet/wsgi.py", line 390, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/eventlet/wsgi.py", line 419, in handle_one_request
    self.raw_requestline = self._read_request_line()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/eventlet/wsgi.py", line 402, in _read_request_line
    return self.rfile.readline(self.server.url_length_limit)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/socket.py", line 589, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/eventlet/green/ssl.py", line 241, in recv_into
    return self._base_recv(nbytes, flags, into=True, buffer_=buffer)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/eventlet/green/ssl.py", line 256, in _base_recv
    read = self.read(nbytes, buffer_)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/eventlet/green/ssl.py", line 176, in read
    super(GreenSSLSocket, self).read, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/eventlet/green/ssl.py", line 150, in _call_trampolining
    return func(*a, **kw)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 926, in read
    raise ValueError("Read on closed or unwrapped SSL socket.")
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 498, in send
ValueError: Read on closed or unwrapped SSL socket.
Removing descriptor: 8
142f38bdaaf34c7e8883e99a766fe310: Unexpected error "Read on closed or unwrapped SSL socket.", closing connection
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))
```

Please give me some ideas! Thanks in advance.

Comment: The Flask-SocketIO server includes a [stop()](https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#flask_socketio.SocketIO.stop) method that you can use to notify the server to shutdown. The complication in your case is that this method needs to be called from a handler. What you can do is send a request to the server from your signal handler, wait for the request to return, then exit the handler and let the application continue to let the server end gracefully.

Comment: @Miguel Thanks for the response! I will try it.

Comment: @Miguel Hi, I tried to send a request to stop the server. But some exceptions raised. You can see the updated question for information. Is it because the code did not wait the request to return? How can I fix the problem?

Comment: These errors are typical of terminating a server process, and I am not sure there is an actual problem.  Anytime I shutdown my gevent services I get a slew of errors of aborted connections, I would just trap and disregard if you don't want to see them.

Comment: I have never seen this error, but it is likely related to not waiting until the server is fully closed to exit the process.

Comment: @Miguel Do you know how to let the server fully close in my case?

Comment: @Tyrion did you try waiting for the server to gracefully exit?

Comment: @Miguel I don't know how to do it right now. Would you please give me any clue?

Comment: @Tyrion there are a few ways to do this. One way is to prevent the signal from ending the process. That will allow the server to exit gracefully and at that time the process will end as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use in my projects, works great using gevent.  Make sure you start your server AFTER you init your signal.  The signal should be identical, just minus the gevent part.

```
  def shutdown():
        print('Shutting down ...')
        server.stop(timeout=60)
        exit(signal.SIGTERM)
  gevent.signal(signal.SIGTERM, shutdown)
  gevent.signal(signal.SIGINT, shutdown) #CTRL C
  server.serve_forever()
```

Comment: Hi, yes, it works for gevent. But I need to find a solution for using eventlet. But still thank you for your idea and help!

Comment: You can just mirror this using `signal.signal` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. Actually that was what I did in the beginning. But the server could not be stopped in the shutdown function directly. From the documentation given by @Miguel, I need to stop the flask-socketio server by calling a HTTP request or SocketIO handler function.